# C# multiple query selection n th basis of text in drop down list

Tags: c#, sql

i want to run one query at a time on the basis of if statment but everytime only monthly is executed if i click anyother option than to monthly is executed.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HO-IT-049;Initial Catalog=Estatment;Integrated Security=True");
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Regist", con);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE Quaterly ='" + ddl1.SelectedItem.Value + "'", con);
    if (ddl1.SelectedItem.Text == "Monthly")
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Registration WHERE Monthly ='" + ddl1.SelectedItem.Value + "'", con);
    }
    if (ddl1.SelectedItem.Text == "Quaterly")
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE Quaterly ='" + ddl1.SelectedItem.Value + "'", con);

    }
    if (ddl1.SelectedItem.Text == "BiAnnually")
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE BiAnnually ='" + ddl1.SelectedItem.Value + "'", con);
    }
    if (ddl1.SelectedItem.Text == "Annually")
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE Annually ='" + ddl1.SelectedItem.Value + "'", con);
    }
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        // Label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        String Reportpath = Server.MapPath("Report.rdlc");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Reportpath))
        {
            ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[1];
            param[0] = new ReportParameter("myPara", "MyParamValue");

            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Reportpath;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer1.Report.rdlc";
            Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource dataset = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);

            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataset);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        }
    }

    else
    {
        //lblRecordFound.Text = "Data not found";
        ReportViewer1.Reset();
        //ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    }
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Beware of [Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: You forgot to add your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should care for the [SQL Injection](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0926bc/sql-injection/). What I see in your code is that your `SelectedItem.Text` is equal to the name of the column and thus this is what I think can solve your problem. With out using `If-else`

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HO-IT-049;Initial Catalog=Estatment;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    sqlq = "Select * from Registration WHERE " + ddl1.SelectedItem.Text + " = @paramdata";
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        //Have a look at the DataType in the Database
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@paramdata",SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = ddl1.SelectedItem.Value;
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, connection))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Paramdata is the parameter you wanted to pass to the query. Try it to see if it works or not ??

Answer (score 0):

I think in Registration table make single column time and then store there monthly, Quaterly, yearly information and on dropdown selected index change function call

```
 if (ddl1.SelectedItem.index!= 0)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Registration WHERE time='" + ddl1.SelectedItem.Value + "'", con);
    }
```